# aspnet usercontrol collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control like:

```
<my:menu ID="menu" runat="server">
</my:menu>
```

Now I need to store a collection inside the user control, like:

```
<my:menu ID="menu" runat="server">
    <values>
        <value>aaa</value>
        <value>aaa</value>
    </values>
</my:menu>
```

But I'm not sure how to build the structure to hold the values and read the values in the usercontrol page load.

I tried to create a public class values with a public value inside it. But it's not working.

Any tip?

Comment: I think your best bet here is for a public property of type List<string> and set it in the code behind. I'm not sure what value being able to set it in the markup brings. Not what you are looking for though admittedly

Answer (score 1):

You need a `[ParseChildren(true,"Values")]` attribute on your calss also `[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]` attribute on your property.

Comment: Isn't this just for custom controls rather than user controls?

Comment: Yep, this won't work for user controls. You can't nest your own child controls inside a usercontrol. A custom server control is needed.

Comment: It should work, but you should add controls in UserControl code behind like this `foreach (var item in Values) Controls.Add(item);` in page load

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public property of any type in the code behind of the usercontrol.

```
public string MenuValues
{
           get
            {
                return _menuValues;
            }
            set
            {
                _menuValues = value;
            }
}
```

Then you can set them like this:

```
<my:menu ID="menu" runat="server" MenuValues="A,B,D,W,Q,R" />
```

**Edit:**

Since you're looking for a better solution, you'll have to create a **custom** server control, since you can't nest child controls in a Web User Control.

You'll need to use the PersistenceMode attribute to do this. Here's a sample property:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
public ScriptReferenceCollection ScriptReferences
{
    get
    {
        if (scriptReferenceCollection == null)
        {
            if (scriptReferenceArrayList == null)
            {
                this.EnsureChildControls();
                if (scriptReferenceArrayList == null)
                    scriptReferenceArrayList = new ArrayList();
            }
            scriptReferenceCollection = new ScriptReferenceCollection(scriptReferenceArrayList);
        }
        return scriptReferenceCollection;
    }
}
```

Then I could add ScriptReferences like this:

```
<uc1:MyUserControl ID="MyUserControl1" runat="server">
    <ScriptReferences>
        ...
    </ScriptReferences>
</uc1:MyUserControl>
```

Comment: For a better solution, you can create a custom control to add values like that. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using [Templated User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx). Please check it out.